# Defining my Custom devise authentication strategy throws 'load_missing_constant' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my app, I am trying to define a custom strategy but it throws some errors... Here's what I am doing:

```
# myrailsapp/lib/devise/strategies
require 'devise/strategies/database_authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class CustomAuth < Devise::Strategies::DatabaseAuthenticatable
      def valid?
        Rails.logger.info("\n\nIn CustomAuth.valid\n\n")
        true
      end
      def authenticate!
        Rails.logger.info("\n\nCalled My Authenticate!\n\n")
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:custom_auth, Devise::Strategies::CustomAuth)

# config/initializer.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  # manager.strategies.add(:custom_auth, Devise::Strategies::CustomAuth)
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :custom_auth
end
```

When I try to run this, I get this error:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:490:in `load_missing_constant': Expected app/helpers/custom_auth.rb to define CustomAuth (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`const_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in`const_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:501:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`const_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in`const_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:501:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`const_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in`const_missing'
    from /home/rjain/src/qbol/tapp/config/initializers/devise.rb:212

Now, when I move the same file to my app/helpers directory, I get the same error, but if I remove the module Devise and module Strategies, things start to work. Two questions:

1. How to ensure that I can create the file in my lib/devise/strategies folder?
2. How to make it work so that I can use it within Devise::Strategies module as I described above?